How do I render diffuse indirect as separate render layer
I'm trying to render diffuse indirect as separate render layer I want to show only light which is yellow which bounce back forom rifle and soldier.

I watched this YT video but cant figure out how to set it up

Edit: A want to make VFX in blender, basically I have footage with character and "stick" in his hands which mimics rifle. Now I want to add CG rifle in his hands where stick is and then I want to add model of 3D character in place where actor is in footage so it can catch light which came from muzzle flush and bounced from 3D character when shooting happen and that pass is called Diffuse Indirect in view port shading
